# ACTION_PICK with MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI allowing users to pick images synced via picasa (not on device?)

Tags: android-intent

I was testing our app on a tablet and phone both running ICS and using the same Google account. If I take a photo on one it will show up on the other device (syncing via Picasa). The weird thing is that photo shows up on both devices when I do the normal

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

to let the user pick an image from the gallery. My onActivityResult() looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return; // user cancelled
    }

    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    if (imageUri == null) {
        // (code to show error message goes here)
        return;
    }

    // Get image path from media store
    String[] filePathColumn = { android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

    if(cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // (code to show error message goes here)
        return;
    }

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    if (imagePath == null) {
        // error happens here
    }
}
```

Everything is fine until the end when imagePath is null. The code works perfectly for other photos on the device but not the synced one. After adding a bit of logging code it looks like this is happening to some of our users in production, albeit very rarely (less than 1 out of 10,000 photos).

I understand that ACTION_GET_CONTENT has the EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY flag to only show local files, but this is only available on API version 11 and up. ACTION_GET_CONTENT also has  CATEGORY_OPENABLE to only show data that can be opened. Is my ACTION_PICK intent somehow (incorrectly?) showing photos that aren't actually local or openable? According to the documentation, using INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is only supposed show photos stored internally.

Or are there any issues with my onActivityResult() code? I've seen a ton of different variations:

- checking to make sure data.getData().getPath() isn't null
- using MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA as the projection instead of MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
- using MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA as the projection instead of MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
- using managedQuery() to get the Cursor instead of getContentResolver().query()
- using CursorLoader to get the Cursor (API 11+)
- using getColumnIndexOrThrow() instead of getColumnIndex()
- calling cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA) and THEN calling cursor.moveToFirst()
- using "userImage" as the column name (parameter for getColumnIndex())

Would any of these changes fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had [similar problem described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284592/unable-to-select-particular-images-using-action-pick-intent).

I fixed it by opening an InputStream directly from the Intent URI using ContentResolver:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == ACTIVITYRESULT_CHOOSEPICTURE) {
    final InputStream ist = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist);
    ist.close();
  }
}
```