# Unable to select particular images using ACTION_PICK intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using an intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

And in `onActivityResult()` I have this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return; // user cancelled
    }

    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    if (imageUri == null) {
        // (code to show error message goes here)
    return;
    }

    // Get image path from media store
    String[] filePathColumn = { android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn,
            null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // (code to show error message goes here)
        return;
    }

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    if (imagePath == null) {
        // error happens here
    }
}
```

When I select images from particular albums like *"Posts"*, *"Profile Photos"* (see screenshot) I'm unable to get the image path in `onActivityResult()`. Images from other albums can be selected with no problems.

[image: Galley screenshot]

I've tried adding `intent.putExtra("return-data", true)` but `data.getExtras()` returns `null` in `onActivityResult()`.

There is [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078870/action-pick-with-mediastore-images-media-internal-content-uri-allowing-users-to), but no one answered it.

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hops this will helps you ....

ACTIVITYRESULT_CHOOSEPICTURE is the int you use when calling startActivity(intent, requestCode);

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == ACTIVITYRESULT_CHOOSEPICTURE) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    final InputStream ist = ontext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist, null, options);
    ist.close();
  }
}
```

if above code doesn't work than just refer this link... it will surly shows the way

http://dimitar.me/how-to-get-picasa-images-using-the-image-picker-on-android-devices-running-any-os-version/

Comment: It also help me.  Great Job. But one question sometimes it takes too much time to get back in activity and display selected image in view. Any idea why it takes time to load ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String selectedImagePath = imageUri.getEncodedPath();
```

it works for me using gallery image picker

maybe this:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
```

Comment: This gives me a file path similar to this: /picasa/item/5769844615871490082.
But when I try to decode it with BitmapFactory.decodeFile I get Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /picasa/item/5769844615871490082: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). Do I need to process this file path somehow?

Comment: i put edit up maybe that will get it through uri from data.getData() im not sure what that problem is i never had it, maybe the images arent on the phones file system, idk

Comment: if you figure it out please let me know, i fear i may run into the same problem.

Comment: This worked for me:
final InputStream ist = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist);
Thanks for you help.

Comment: there are cases where you might use getData and others, the temp file... so the best is to check for if getData() is !=null, then use that, else use the temp file used during the intent output file