# read all image files in gallery on android

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, android-gallery

When I read from the following two locations, only some of the photos are read:

```
File appStorage = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Downloaded photos for example are not read. Yet, if I manually open the gallery app, I see all my photos in there.

So how do I read all images that are in the gallery? Basically, where do I look?

EDIT:

I really think my question quite obvious, but for some reason people seem to be stuck on `ACTION_PICK`. I am looking for exactly what I say I am looking for above. If I wanted to use `ACTION_PICK`, I would use the following code:

```
public void dispatchGalleryIntent(View view) {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, LOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

I don't need my user to pick images from the gallery. No. What I need is for the app itself to load all the images that are in the gallery. I am really not sure how else to say this.

NOTE:

In case more clarification is needed, here is the code I am using to read the files I mention in the OP (i.e., `appStorage` and `externalStorage`):

```
void addFiles(final File parent, Set<File> images) {
    try {
        for (final File file : parent.listFiles()) {
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                images.add(file);
            } else {
                addFiles(file, images);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reading directly from the sdcard by giving the absolute path

Comment: @Srikanth I don't understand the suggestion. My app is trying to find all the images in a user's library. How do I know what the absolute path is?

Comment: Do you just want to open gallery for user to pick from? You can do that with an intent

Comment: @JRowan: No. This is exactly how I mean it. I am not looking for `Intent.ACTION_PICK`.

Comment: You should look at MediaStore API by Android. MediaScanner does all scanning for you and saved it in ContentProvider. You can query for results. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html

Comment: Maybe something along these lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284592/unable-to-select-particular-images-using-action-pick-intent like picasa pics and such are a different code process to obtain

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

You will need to filter the correct extensions such as `jpg, png, etc`.

EDIT:

You are correct. Mine is not a great solution as you get all kind of weird images that you don't even know exists on your device. I was just trying to veer people to the right direction so maybe someone with better information can answer you.

On the other hand, on my particular device, all my images are good if I leave out the `Android` sub-directory as in `/storage/sdcard0/Android/...`. But I can't say this is a final answer as I don't now how other devices would behave. You essentially need to know how the gallery app does it or better yet how to piggyback the gallery app and get everything it sees. Maybe by using some sort of cursor, which I don't know how to use.

Comment: +1 for addressing my question. When I try that it returns anything and everything with an image extension, such as wall papers. If you ever try it you will see what I mean. But I want the images that would show up in the user's gallery sub-folders, no more. Basically, I don't want a user to be able to see an image in their gallery that my app is not able to show them. But no images additional to these.

Comment: I try the `Android` filter. There is indeed a tremendous reduction in trash but I still get a few images from `DCIM` on my device. There is no telling what a user might see from some other non-gallery directory.